# How to make Photoshop CS6 open 32-bit depth file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-format, tiff, bit

I have PS CS6 installed and a couple of 32 floating point TIFFs I'd like to process. The problem is, though on that on a basic search on Google I've seen 32 bit is supported, I keep getting the error: *The TIFF file uses an unsupported bit depth*. Any ideas how to make this work?